# What are steps to setup SSO in spnego or waffle in embedded JETTY?

Tags: java, maven, embedded-jetty, spnego, waffle

What are steps to setup SSO in spnego or waffle in embedded Jetty?

I tried [Embedded Jetty Validation](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Source/JNA/waffle-jetty/src/test/java/waffle/jetty/StartEmbeddedJettyValidateNTLMGroup.java) approach.

It fails when i try to setup filter init filter params and add it to context via handler

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext@3453a820 findOrCreate returned a null for descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent$WebComponentBinder$3
    contracts={javax.servlet.ServletContext}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=PROVIDE_METHOD
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@133fb509
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=122
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=573963719
    reified=true) and handle null
```